# Placing JavaScript functions inside of an object of a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

I see this quite often, but I'm not sure as to the purpose of it or what the advantages would be (if any).
Placing a function or sets of functions inside of an object, as a value for a variable.

```
var variableName = { (function() {DO STUFF} )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses global variables. That means every script cann access and modify all variables and possible overwrite variables with the same name.
To secure your own script, you can use a global variable (like var MyScript=... ) and write everything into it.
To give an example, I wrote a simple script to navigate between html-files.
You can see a variable called 'Navi' which capsulates all the stuff inside.
It contains variables and functions and (in this case) access is allowed only by the returned names.
If I wrote functions next and previous out of Navi, they may be overwritten in some other scripts.

```
var Navi = (function(){
    var currentPage = 0;
    var pages = [];
    pages[0] = "first.html";
    pages[1] = "second.html";
    pages[2] = "third.html";

    var next = function next(){
        if(currentPage < pages.length - 1){
            currentPage++;
            location.href = pages[currentPage];
        }
    };

    var previous = function previous(){
        if(currentPage > 0){
            currentPage--;
            location.href = pages[currentPage];
        }
    };

    return{
        next: next,
        previous: previous,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        pages: pages
    };
})();
```

To call it from a html file:

```
<a href="javascript:Navi.previous();">previous page</a>
<a href="javascript:Navi.next();">next page</a>
```

So far.

Comment: Script can modify all variables? Can you elaborate.

Comment: So it's just a security feature, like in procedural programming where you can set classes to private?

Also, wouldn't other scripts be allowed to alter the global variable then that everything is wrapped inside, thus breaking everything?

Comment: @specialscope: 
As far as I know, JS parsers work from top of a document to bottom. Variables / functions / objects etc. will be overwritten, if they are declared another time with the same name.
E.g. we use two script:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="navigation.js"...>`
`<script ... src="anotherScript.js">...`
Let's assume the 'next'-function in navigation.js is not within another variable.
It will be set as:
`var next = function(){`
`   // change the url `
`  }};`
The second script contains a line: `var next = "from this point, next this is just a string";`
Is it reasonable for you?

Comment: in the script to the original post I should alter the return value to `return{next: next,previous: previous,currentPage: currentPage}` without access to 'pages' (ok for debugging) and maybe change 'currentPage' indirectly by a function (eg. to allow numbers in range of pages.length only)

Comment: @KnightYoshi: as the code-sample above demonstrates variables, objects, functions and so one may be altered beside your own scripts. So their is the chance, you overwrite someone others variables and other way around.  
tip 1: Try to give your capsulating variable (the global one) a name, that hopefully is not used in any script afterwards.  
tip 2: keep in mind JavaScript is case-sensitive *g*

Answer (score 0):

Basically if the function had a name you could call it with

variableName.function(args);

In these kinds of objects you can set your methods that will be stored in the object at all times until you refresh or reset the data yourself, this is handy if you want to make things dynamic but still memorize the input data.

You can make a singleton object like this:

```
var Singleton = {

    data1 : '',

    functionName : function() {

        this.data1 = document.getElementById('formfield1').value;    

    }

}
```

so if you have a formfield with an id of formfield1

```
<input type="text" id="formfield1" value="" />
```

when you bind this function to a submit button for instance

```
<button onclick="Singleton.functionName();">Save</button>
```

Your info will be stored in the data1 variable in the object.

There is alot more to it than this but it is a good way of saving data, hope it helped :)